# Turn "Google Developer Console" on

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-developers-console

I have to Turn on "Google Developer Console" in my "Admin Console > Apps > Additional Google Services" but I can't find it. 
I am Super-Admin. 
I need to use Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this to that the Developer Console as a G-Suite Business User. Support told me that this is a bug and I'm not the only one.

At this time there is no fix/workaround.